# How to document the empty body for 2xx response code with Swagger-UI

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

In Swagger 2.0 in Java (io.springfox springfox-swagger-ui 2.9.2)

```
  @ApiResponse(code = 204, message = "No data found for given key", response = Void.class)
```

(Void.class is also default, same result if ommited) this code generates standard response model (string in my case) in schema field.

Whereas

```
  @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "No key found", response = Void.class)
```

works as expected (no schema field) - empty body.

How do I document empty body response with 2xx codes?

Comment: I think there's a relevant github issue with a workaround - https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1944. Does using "void.class" instead of "Void.class" work?

Comment: nope, the void.class and Void.class -> the same default model.